# Convert time field stored as an integer to 24 hour format

Tags: r

I have several time fields that store time as an integer (for instance 12:06 am is stored as 6, 7:10 pm is stored as 1910).  I need to convert this into a time format that I can then merge (join) with my date field.  Preferably to look like this when I am done: 2/28/2017 22:38.

Answer (score 0):

A POSIXct object stores datetimes as "seconds since 1970-01-01". You will have to convert minutes to seconds, then add that to midnite of the date in question, then convert that to a POSIXct object.

Here's how you would treat "6" (i.e. 12:06am today)

```
> as.POSIXct("2019-04-10 00:00:00") + 6 * 60
[1] "2019-04-10 00:06:00 PDT"
```

You can use `format` if you only want to keep the time:

```
> dateTime = as.POSIXct("2019-04-10 00:00:00") + 6 * 60
> dateTime
[1] "2019-04-10 00:06:00 PDT"
> format(dateTime, format = "%H:%M:%S")
[1] "00:06:00"
```